# Java Spring: get current mapping in the controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How do you get the current mapping with query Params but without the base-URL in a controller? e.g. `/foo/bar?boom=bam`?

I tried using a UriComponentsBuilder as a parameter in the controller, but that results in `http://localhost`,

I tried using ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath(), but that results in `http://localhost?boom=bam`.

I just want the current mapping with the queryparams without having to parse things

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the HttpServletRequest as a controller method argument and query that:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-methods

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

```
public void controllerMethod(HttpServletRequest request){
        String path = request.getServletPath();
        String queryString = request.getQueryString();
    }
```